# PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a procedure which updates a transaction table according to the transaction type... but i am unable to correct the error: `PL/SQL: Statement ignored`
My code is :

```
create or replace procedure proc(acn transaction.acctno%TYPE, tt transaction.transtype%TYPE, amt transaction.amount%TYPE, bal transaction.balance%TYPE, dt transaction.dot%TYPE)
IS
ano transaction.acctno%TYPE;
ba transaction.balance%TYPE;
BEGIN
select acctno,balance into ano,bno from transaction where accctno=acn;
if tt='W' and bno>500 
then
update transaction set balance=balance-amt;
elsif tt='D'
then
update transaction set balance=balance+amt;
else
dbms_output.put_line('Insufficient balance');
end if;
END;
```

full error:

```
ERROR at line 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

5. BEGIN
6. select acctno,balance into ano,bno from transaction where accctno=acn;
7. if tt='W' and bno>500 
8. then
9. update transaction set balance=balance-amt;
```

Comment: That's the whole message? No data about which statement is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first thought that the error is because your table name is `transaction` which is a reserved word:

```
select * from v$reserved_words where lower(keyword) = 'transaction';
```

This is not the case however. But it seemst that the variable `bno` into which you want to select is not declared. You have, however, declared another variable `ba transaction.balance%TYPE;`. Proboably, you should update the variable name either in the declaration or in the statement so that both are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your update statements are updating the entire table. You probably want to "select for update", and then update "where current of".